# How should I subtract two vectors or matrices from each other without NumPy?

Tags: python

I have a function that subtracts one matrix of some shape (a nested list) from another matrix of the same shape (assumed to be a nested list of the same size):

```
def subtract(matrix_a, matrix_b):
    MATRIX_LENGTH = len(matrix_a)
    MATRIX_ROW = len(matrix_a[0])
    for i in range(MATRIX_LENGTH):
      for j in range(MATRIX_ROW):
        matrix_a[i][j] -= matrix_b[i][j]
    return matrix_a
```

The above function iterates through each value of matrix_a and subtracts the value at the same position of matrix_b from matrix_a before returning matrix_a.

This code does not work if I supply a vector (an "un"-nested list). For example, supplying [1, 2, 3, 4] and [2, 3, 4, 5] to matrix_a and matrix_b respectively will yield `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`.

How should I modify the function to accept "un"-nested lists? For educational purposes, I do not want to use NumPy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply check the type of the first element and run an altered version if the first element is not a list. Also, I suggest creating a new array as the result, but either way it works.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama Thank you for your response! Instead of checking the type (both a vector and a matrix are lists), I thought of using a try/except/else to catch the TypeError, thanks to you. I'll post an answer just in case anyone needs this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip to pair up the values/rows in a list comprehension, and call the function recursively for nested dimensions:

```
def subtract(A,B):
     if isinstance(A,list):
         return [ subtract(ra,rb) for ra,rb in zip(A,B) ]
     else:
         return A-B
```

*This will work for any number of dimensions*

To process operands of different dimensions, you can refine the function to make it check both parameter types to determine the result:

```
def subtract(A,B):
     dims = isinstance(A,list) + 2 * isinstance(B,list)
     if dims == 3: # both ar lists
         return [ subtract(ra,rb) for ra,rb in zip(A,B) ]
     if dims == 2: # only B is a list
         return [ subtract(A,rb) for rb in B ]
     if dims == 1: # only A is a list
         return [ subtract(ra,B) for ra in A ]
     return A-B
    
print(subtract([[3,4],[7,8]],[1,2])) # [[2, 3], [5, 6]]
print(subtract([3,4],[1,2]))         # [2, 2]
print(subtract([10,20,30],5))        # [5, 15, 25]
print(subtract(50,[10,20,30]))       # [40, 30, 20]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! Just as a follow up, is there any way we can use this method for a function that deals with scalar multiplication? I have both vectors (unnested list) and matrices (nested list) that need to be multiplied by some scalar.

Comment: It would be very similar but you may need to have different functions for operations between operands of different dimensions.  Even if you end up wrapping them all into a dispatching function that selects which one to call, it will be easier to implement and test.  You should ask a new question in SO for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LarrytheLlama, I thought of using a try/except/else statement to catch the TypeError. The following code subtracts two vectors or matrices from each other without NumPy:

```
def subtract(matrix_a, matrix_b):
  MATRIX_LENGTH = len(matrix_a)
  try:
    MATRIX_ROW = len(matrix_a[0])
  except TypeError:
    for i in range(MATRIX_LENGTH):
      matrix_a[i] -= matrix_b[i]
  else:
    for i in range(MATRIX_LENGTH):
      for j in range(MATRIX_ROW):
        matrix_a[i][j] -= matrix_b[i][j]
  return matrix_a
```

Comment: You can use `isinstance(matrix_a[0], list)` to prevent error catching to begin with.